# Proving modular arithmetic using its contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I am given this sort of problem:

Prove the following statement using a proof by contraposition.

$∀n∈Z$, if $n^2 \bmod 5=1$ then, $n \bmod 5=1$ or $n \bmod 5=4.$

So, the contrapositive would be:

$∀n∈Z$, if $n\bmod 5≠1$ or $n\bmod 5≠4$ then, $n^2\bmod 5≠1$

My problem here is how would you prove that such elements do not equal to each other?

Comment: there are only $5$ residue classes $\pmod 5$.  Just check all of them.

Comment: As a general matter, in any field an element can have at most two square roots.  But, in this case, direct computation is so easy that there's no reason to fall back on abstract methods.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ compute $0=n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$. Hence either $n=1$ or $n=-1=4$. But of course, lulu is right. We can see this directly.

Comment: Yeah I know the mod 5 classes but I'm not sure how to approach it by proving its contrapositive

Comment: But...if $n\not \equiv \pm 1\pmod 5$ then $n\equiv 0,2,3\pmod 5$.  Just confirm that none of those square to $1$.

Comment: The contrapositive would be if $n \mod 5 \ne 1$ **and** $n \mod 5 \ne 4...$

Comment: $\!\large \bmod 5\!:\,\ n\not\equiv \pm1\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv 0,\pm2\,\Rightarrow\, n^2 \equiv \ldots \not\equiv 1$ $\ \ $